# How to get the real pixel value of left/right margin if an element is set margin: 0 auto in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, margin

With jquery, I can use element.css('margin-left') to get the real pixel value of an elment's margin if it has `margin: 0 auto;`. But it seems that this doesn't work in IE8. It always returns `auto`. So how can get the pixel value in IE8?

Comment: Is this straight from the body? or is there a container element? is it fixed or fluid width?

Comment: I'm sure It returns true answer ,there is something in your code, if you have absolute positioned element , It will remove from flow of the page, can u share your code